# Windows form app elements not showing in c# file

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms-designer

I'm in Visual Studio 2019.  I'm following along with an instructional video on creating a simple Windows Forms C# app.  I've added some elements like buttons and labels and texts fields from the toolbox, and I've saved.  But when I flip over to the C# file, I don't see any code related to these.  The video (and other similar videos) seem to show that if the user looks there, they will see the methods already there, reflecting what was done in the GUI.  Why would I not see the same thing?

Comment: Unless you add an event handler such as click or drag, they will live in Designer.cs file separated from the main file.

Comment: Thanks for your input, Martheen.  It seems that my problem was even more basic.  I was not double-clicking on the element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example Form:

[image]

When you double click on button from design click event code generate automatically:

[image]

If you go to properties of button then to events: you can see click event with method name

[image]

Comment: Yes!  I was missing the double-click step.  This helps a lot.  Thanks!